# How can I use Smarty templates with A/B testing?

Tags: testing, smarty

I am attempting to build a little modification in our code to allow easier A/B testing.

I'd like to know if I can somehow

1. have my regular code under the /templates directory
2. have any a/b code under /templates/_abtests/, but also follow the same hierarchy as the regular code.  for example... an ab test can overwrite a file like '/templates/foo.tpl', and use instead '/templates/_abtests/testfoo/foo.tpl'

I tried changing the template directory when in a test. Right before calling the display method, I would check if a user is in a test, and if so, set up the template_dir accordingly. I'd assign an array with the 'ab' directory first, then the default.  I am using Smarty2.

the problem with this is that it caches the first instance, and uses that as the template for the baseline and ab test case.  ie: i have a parameter to force me into a test bucket, but the template is the same.

thoughts on how to achieve this?  goal is to not have to add a bunch of template hooks (if/else) in the templates. and achieve this by simple template/file includes.

Comment: The problem is that smarty caches your template?

Comment: yes. I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the solution to my problem could be to put templates into folders.  ie: /templates/base/, /templates/test_foo/, etc.".  then in my template_dir setting, set the array up based on what test we are in.

I had tried this with mobile/desktop before, and forgot about this solution.

I can extend the smarty_template class and override the display method to change the template_dir.  adding the test directory first.